# Recuperar el valor de un select de un formulario

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Tengo un formulario con un solo select en donde se llena automáticamente de una tabla de mysql, el detalle es que quiero que cuando alguien seleccione una opción y le de clic en el botón de enviar, pueda recuperar ese valor para poder hacer una consulta y mostrar los datos, no es como un select dependiente, mas bien en mi select tengo los datos de unas carreras, si selecciono una después me aparecen los datos de las materias de esa carrera junto con otras especificaciones.

El problema es que no sé como recuperar el valor enviado por el select.

Mi código es este:

```
{!!Form::open(['route' => 'plan.mostrar','method' => 'POST'])!!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {!!Form::label('Seleccione RVOE:')!!}
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i>
            </div>

            {!!Form::select('rvoe',$rvoe,null,['id' => 'rvoe','class' => 'form-control'])!!}

            </div>
    </div>

    {!!Form::submit('Enviar',['name' => 'guardar','id' => 'guardar','content' => '<span>Enviar</span>','class' => 'btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right'])!!}

{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu controlador puedes inyectar (usando la inyección de dependencias) un request, el cual es en este caso el POST realizado al momento de enviar el formulario.

routes.php

```
Route::post('carrera', 'PlanController@mostrar')->name('plan.mostrar');
```

Controlador:

```
namespace app\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PlanController extends Controller
{

    public function mostrar(Request $request)
    {
        // selecciona directamente el valor seleccionado del select
        $carrera = $request->input('rvoe');

        // puedes obtener todos los valores enviados en el request en forma de array
        // $valores = $request->all();
    }

}
```

También puedes reemplazar el `$request` genérico que estamos usando por uno personalizado que incluya validaciones de los campos del formulario e incluso verificación de permisos si lo necesita tu aplicación.

Puedes ver toda la información relacionada con esta respuesta en la documentación oficial de Laravel: [Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests) y [Validaciones](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#form-request-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Las opción que miro yo, es la siguiente.

```
<select value = "" name="valor">
 @if($valor != null)
    <option value="{{$valor}}" selected="" > Carrera1 </option>
 @endif
</select>
```

en el controlador

```
public function mostrar(Request $request){
  $valor = $request->get("valor");
  return redirect->route("formulario",[valor = $valor]);
}
```

Lo que hago es :

1. Defino el valor en la plantilla , donde defino el `@if` donde lo que
   digo es si existe este valor que lo seleccione en la plantilla como
   `selected`.
2. En el Controlador , capturo la respuesta del formulario y lo devuelvo por medio del router , donde tienes que crear un ruta personalizada:

   route::get("formulario/{carrera}")->name("formulario");

Lo que faltaría es definir en js , que si existe o que lo complete con las materias relacionadas con la carrera.